# contentEditable div allow only TEXT and IMG tag

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, contenteditable

If I have an `contentEditable` div can I remove all HTML elements except for `IMG` with specific class. I asked a question about that, but I have troubles with it. The problem is that Google Chrome uses `div`s as lines break / separator, Internet Explorer uses `p`, and the Mozilla Firefox uses only `<br>`.

How can I remove all HTML elements Except for Images from the `contentEditable` div, and keep lines, for all browsers?

I used :

```
   var element = document.getElementById("myDiv");
   for(var i=0; i<element.children.length;i++)
   {
     if(element.children[i].tagName != "IMG" || 
        element.children[i].className != "requiredClassName")
     {
       element.insertBefore(document.createTextNode(element.children[i].innerHTML.replace(/<\/?.*?\/?>/gi, ''), element.children[i]);
       element.children[i].parentNode.removeChild(element.children[i]);
     }
   }
```

But it causes troubles in IE and Chrome, it removes all lines, and all text became in one long line.

I need only pure JavaScript code.

Comment: i know that with jQuery it is easier, but i need pure javascript